# Can't add a foreign key constraint in a table on Postgresql

Tags: foreign-key, constraint, postgresql-9.2

I'm trying to add a foreign key of "prefectures" table in "centresdevote" table.
But I'm having this error while trying to add a foreign key to "centresdevote" table.
I had no problem adding foreign keys to other tables in my database by the way, and I can't seem to figure out why this error pops up only for this one.
I'm working on Postgresql 9.2 and I've added the foreign keys for the other tables manually. I tried also using SQL code as follows :

```
ALTER TABLE centresdevote 
ADD CONSTRAINT objectid 
FOREIGN KEY (objectid) REFERENCES prefectures (objectid);
```

Here's the error

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "centresdevote " violates foreign key constraint "objectid"
DETAIL:  Key (objectid)=(10) is not present in table "prefectures".
```

Here's the structure of the two tables :

"prefectures" table :

```
objectid integer NOT NULL,
nomprefecture character varying(70),
shape st_geometry,
respcommissionrecensement character varying(70),
CONSTRAINT prefectures_pkey PRIMARY KEY (objectid)
```

"centresdevote" table :

```
objectid integer NOT NULL,
arabicname character varying(70),
frenchname character varying(70),
shape st_point,
CONSTRAINT centresdevote_pkey PRIMARY KEY (objectid)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the table `centresdevote` you have a row where the value of `objectid` is 10. As you are trying to create a `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` there is a check that there is a matching value in the column `objectid` in the table `prefectures` for all the rows in `centresdevote`. In `prefectures` there is no row with `objectid = 10`.

I suggest you read [The PostgreSQL Documentation - 5.3.5. Foreign Keys](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) and the [W3Schools page about foreign keys](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp). The whole point of the foreign keys is that they limit what you can insert into the field. From PostgreSQL Documentation:

> A foreign key constraint specifies that the values in a column (or a group of columns) must match the values appearing in some row of another table. We say this maintains the referential integrity between two related tables.

Adding foreign key is not mandatory and you can do every kind of query without it.

Comment: Thank you @simo Kivistö for your quick reply. Indeed I only have 9 rows in "prefectures" table, while I have 46 rows in "centresdevote" table. But that's the data I have, what am I supposed to do then ?

Comment: While adding foreign keys for the other tables I have, and although the number of rows weren't the same for the concerned tables I didn't have this error. How come?

Comment: Error in your data? Is there a missing préfecture?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Vérace. Well I have 9 rows in préfecture table, and 46 rows in "centresdevote" table. Does the number of rows in the two tables need to match for the foreign key to be added?! I don't think it should be, right? Otherwise why I didn't have any problem adding a foreign key to other tables knowing that the number of rows aren't matched !

Comment: Added some explanation. The number of rows don't need to match but the values in the columns must match.

Comment: "Does the number of rows in the two tables need to match for the foreign key to be added?"   **NO** - definitely not. But, si j'ai bien compris (AIUI), each CentreDeVote has to be in a Préfecture - so what's happening is that you have a CentreDeVote which (according to objectid) isn't in any Préfecture. Track that one down and see where the error in your data is - it's probably a data entry typo or something similar.

Comment: SimoKivistö Thank u so much for ur explanation. I do understand the concept of foreign keys and I get what you are trying to say.. But I just can't figure out why does the error still persist although the values are matched!
@Vérace une "préfecture" peut inclure plusieurs centres de vote. So it's a 1-n relationship.. This is really confusing as I can't seem to figure out why the error keeps popping..

Comment: The data entries seem fine !

Comment: So if you run `SELECT * FROM prefectures WHERE objectid=10;` you will get one row? And the error message is still `Key (objectid)=(10) is not present in table "prefectures".`?

Comment: @SimoKivistö sorry for my late answer. There is indeed no 10 row in prefectures table, like I mentioned before I only have 9 rows in that table. While in  "centresdevote" I have 46. The objectid column for both tables is serial. Am I supposed to add another column in "centresdevote" table and set it to 9 entries, and use that column as a foreign key to the other table? It's really confusing!

Comment: Yes create a a separate column for the foreiqn key in the table `centresdevote` with the name `prefecture_id` for example. That value tells you in which prefecture the centredevote is in so the value has to be found in the `prefectures` table.

Comment: This does the trick.. Thank u soo much @SimoKivistö !